# Avoid default selection when selecting random value from dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have a method below that selects a random item from a dropdown list. This works well mostly, but on occasion it will reselect the default option which is usually "Please Select" or a blank value.

Im looking at how to avoid selecting the default/already selected option.

Below is my code from my Selenium framework.

```
    public void selectRandomDropDownOption(By dropdownIdentifier, By options) {
    // Putting in a loop to specify number of selections and to then select different values every time.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        // Click on drop down
        clickElement(dropdownIdentifier);
        // Get items in dropdown
        List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(options);
        // Get size of options
        int size = items.size();
        // Generate a random number which will be used to select an item in the list
        int randNo = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, size);
        items.get(randNo).click();
    }
}
```

Example of the DOM (fairly standard)

```
<select name="IPQ_OA_TFINSUP1" id="IPQ_OA_TFINSUP1" onchange="ul_conditional_display_all('FD', 'OA_TFINSUP1');" required="required" class="sv-form-control" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="SVb4935443-ae1b-4cf6-357d-57c92b2da566">

<option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
<option value="ELCAS">ELCAS</option>
<option value="PROF_AND_CAREER">Professional and Career Development Loan</option> etc....
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply filter out the invalid options from the list:

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(options);
List<WebElement> validItems = items.stream()  
                                   .filter(
                                     item -> !(
                                              item.getText().equals("Please Select") 
                                              || item.getText().isEmpty())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Despite there is couple of arguable things in your code (like `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` loop which will be executed a single time) I would suggest to solve your issue before you are entering the method. Your `By` should incorporate the locator that would not include `option` with empty value (or [take all options except first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634122/how-to-ignore-first-element-in-xpath)).

Hence in your method's code you will be randomly picking from options which do not include default one.

**P.S.** - if you still need your method to accept all existing options you can do something like this:

```
int randNo = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, size - 1);
items.get(randNo + 1).click();
```

This will only require to check a special case when `size == 0`;